# Bootstrap rowspan and align control bottom up

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to create following using bootstrap. Three rows in the left, two rows in the right. First row in second column rowspan and vertical align bottom.

[image: Expected output]

here is the html code I tried

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div style='background-color:red'>
                    row1-col1
        </div> 
        <div style='background-color:aqua'> 
                        row2-col1
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col" style='vertical-align:bottom'> 
            <div style='background-color:yellow'> 
                  row1-col2
            </div>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"> 
        <div style='background-color:lightgreen'> 
                   row3-col1
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col">  
        <div  style='background-color:orange'> 
                 row2-col2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the actual output I am getting.
[image: Actual output]

Not sure what am I missing, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to the code you provided. I moved some of the styles around and added the `.equal` class to each col.

Additionally if you are interested in a simple more reliable custom JS script to get the height match effect you want (I don't like bootstraps equalizer).

To add this to both your **row1-col1 - row2-col1** column and **row1-col2** columns - Note: To get the code to work I had to use a lesser version of jQuery (2.1.1 for this example/you can test other versions to see what will work for you) and I shuffled some of the HTML. If the background colors are just for the example then its all set and the column heights will match.

Check out this **new** codepen using your code: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/xMYZeV

```css
.equal {
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col equal">
        <div style='background-color:red'>
                    row1-col1
        </div> 
        <div style='background-color:aqua'> 
                        row2-col1
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col equal" style='vertical-align:bottom; background-color:yellow'> 
            <div  style=''> 
                  row1-col2
            </div>   
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"> 
        <div style='background-color:lightgreen'> 
                   row3-col1
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col">  
        <div  style='background-color:orange'> 
                 row2-col2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @brooksrelyt, may I know how to add the vertical alignment to row1-col2?

Comment: awesome thank you, this is what i was looking to get.